# Rails routing resource with username instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building this app using rails 4 and i wanted to have the routes like this

example.com/users/username

instead of

example.com/users/id

to do this i used [Friendly Id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

Now everything is working so I don't want this route to be accessible

example.com/users/id

should I create the routes individually for all the CRUD actions or is there a way to change this?

```
resources :users do
    resources :post do
      get 'expand'
      get 'current'
    end
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can pass a hash with white or black list of crud actions to resources method.

Example (whitelist)

`resources :users, only: [:index, :edit]`

Example (blacklist)

`resources :users, except: [:show, :delete]`

You should hide 'show' action.

`resources :users, except: [:show]`

also, you can check out this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

Comment: I think i explained myself wrong.
What i don't want is to be able to, for example, go to the user show page using the id. but I still want all the actions
so this would work example.com/users/potato and not this example.com/users/1

Comment: have you fix it? I have new one answer - you can add constrains for format of show/:id, where you can change :id with a some regexp ;)

Comment: Some problems came up and I had to drop the project, but by the time I left i hadn't fixed the problem. Thanks for the tip though